# Rails 3: Join results in a view

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join

Again I'm faced with something that should not on the face of it be this difficult but has been driving me mad for an hour or so. I have multiple models which I want to pull into one 'index' view. I assume it's a join but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

What I have in my index view:

```
    <% @tips.each do |tip| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= tip.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= tip.city_id # here I want to draw on the cities table to show city.name
         %></td>
    <td><%= tip.type_id # here I want to draw on the type table to show type.name
         %></td>
    <td><%= tip.place_id # here I want to draw on the place table to show place.name
         %></td>
    <td><%= tip.tip_desc %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', tip %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tip_path(tip) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tip, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Here are the models:

```
class Tip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :place
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collections
  has_many :tips
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :places
  has_many :tips 
end
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: Sorry, just looked at your comments. Have you tried just <%= tip.city.name %>?

Comment: Hi Calvin, Thanks for your suggestion. The controller is just the standard '@tips = Tip.includes(:city)'. There's no join there. When I try tip.city.name i get the error 'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass'. Any more suggestions? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions from other guys should work. I'm not sure, but it seems like you don't have objects within specified IDs in your database. That's all :)

Example:

```
@tips.each do |tip|
  tip.city_id # 1
  City.find( tip.city_id ) # nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this! You were right. I was able to render the correct text by embedding the following in my  view'<% @c = City.find( tip.city_id )%><%= @c.name%>'.

Sorry, I'm still new at this. You say I don't have objects within the specified ID's in my database. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: So, you're saying that you were able to get city via tip.city_id from database? Then I have no idea why did your association is not working... Maybe you have a method called _city_ in your _Tip_ model?